# Mac OS X 10.9 Broken terminal PATH and bash files

Tags: macos, terminal, macports

I'm new to Mac and I've been trying to install Wine, Installed Macports so far and my terminal has broken. From what I've googled I must've altered bash files but I have no idea where they are and any help was based on commands and I can't enter any in my Terminal.

Here's what I get when I open it:

> Last login: Fri Jul 11 22:17:00 on ttys000
>   -bash: export: `/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/opt/X11/bin': not a
>   valid identifier

I was looking for how to uninstall Macports but all I found was commands.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You can always add a new user if you have messed up the existing one... Apple menu at top left of screen -> Preferences -> User Accounts and add a new one with sysadmin privileges.

Comment: I don't wany new account, I'd like to fix this one